# cannot install pip install torchvision

Tags: python, module, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I am using python 3.8.3 version, I tried to install torchvision and torch module and faced this error, none of them are installed. The error comes as `ERROR:could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.4.0(from versions:0.1.2,0.1.2,post1,0.1.2.post2)`

```
Error:No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0
```

Comment: First upgrade pip

Comment: @jpnadas done as per your advice

Comment: @OsadhiVirochanaJayasingheSi I tried but still seems to be in error

Comment: How are you trying to install it? `pip`, `conda`, compiling from source?

Comment: @jpnadas by using pip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)'s website, you must specify if you are using cpu or the version of CUDA when installing from `pip`.

For instance, if I wanted to install on a Linux system without CUDA, version 1.5.1 of PyTorch, I would run:

```
pip install torch==1.5.1+cpu torchvision==0.6.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

You can use the link I provided above to get the syntax for your specific environment.

Comment: for windows 10?

Comment: go on the link, select windows and follow the instruction.